# Find the number of duplicates in a LinkedList - an edge case test failing

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was asked to code for the following problem:

*Problem Description:*

> Given a **linked list**, find the number of **duplicate elements** in the
> list.
>
> *Input Format:*
>
> First line contains an integer `N` - The number of *nodes*.
>
> Second line contains `N` integers - Node *values*.
>
> *Output Format:*
>
> Print the total number of duplicates.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> `N <= 10^5`
>
> Value of node <= `10^6`

*Sample Input:*

```
9

1 2 3 4 4 5 6 6 6
```

*Sample Output:*

```
3
```

*Explanation:*

In the given test case we have `3` duplicates i.e. one `4` and two `6`.

*My code:*

```
import crio.ds.List.*;
    
    /*public class ListNode {
       public int val;
       public ListNode next;
       public ListNode(int x) { val = x; next = null; }
    }*/
    
    
    public class Solution {
        public int countDuplicatesInALinkedList(ListNode head){
    
            int counter = 0;
            
            while(head.next != null){
    
                ListNode ptr = head.next;
                while(ptr != null){
                    if(head.val == ptr.val){
                        counter++;
                        break;
                    }
                    ptr = ptr.next;
                }
                head = head.next;
            }
            
            return counter;
        }
    }
```

I want to understand why my code is failing the edge case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the *head-node* is `null` your code will produce a `NullPointerException` when it enters the outer `while`-loop (*while evaluating the condition `head.next != null`, which will fail if head is `null`*).

Also, your solution is inefficient. You're checking every value against all others values in the list and takes a quadratic time **O(n^2)** to run.

This problem can be solved in a liner time **O(n)**, in a single pass through the list and fewer code.

For that, you can utilize a `HashSet` which will store every previously encountered value. If an offered value rejected by the *set*, i.e. `seen.add()` returns `false`, that means this value is a duplicate.

```
public int countDuplicatesInALinkedList(ListNode head) {
    
    Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
    int counter = 0;
    
    ListNode current = head;
    
    while (current != null) {
        if (!seen.add(current.val)) { // value has been rejected - i.e. it's a duplicate
            counter++;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

*Sidenote:* it's not considered to be a good practice to modify objects received as method parameters.